# Difference between driver and transistor

Tags: transistors, current, integrated-circuit, driver, 7segmentdisplay

I asked a question earlier question, "[Is it safe to run Logic ICs at their maximum output current?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/408497/is-it-safe-to-run-logic-ics-at-their-maximum-output-current)" asking if it was safe to run logic ICs at their maximum current.

From what I understand, this is not a good idea and instead I should use some sort of 'driver' between my logic system and my displays.

After some searching I found the [SN74HC244N](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1831349.pdf?_ga=2.263768204.1443692333.1542826987-2037417280.1522363209) however, this only has a maximum output current of 6mA at 5V (unless I'm reading the datasheet wrong). This doesn't seem very high to me for a 'driver' IC.

This got me thinking as to why I would want to use one of these chips as opposed to 8 transistors (which I assume could handle higher currents). Is it just ease of use that they are already in one small package or is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a "Line" driver, as in to drive a bus with many other ICs that the previous part of the circuit can't drive.

It has:

- clear I/O Low/High voltage levels,
- low current requirement for input, (with a transistor you need a base current)
- clear propagation delay and push-pull output, (with a single transistor you have open collector or emitter)
- enable pin, so you can have many different drivers drive the same lines (i.e. 64 outputs and 8 inputs, then you enable one driver at a time)
- etc

So its a "driver" for specific purposes on circuits, not a generic driver for LEDs. (There are darlington arrays for example that are made to drive loads, see [ULN200X](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/IC/ULN2003A.pdf) for example).

In essence you are kind of looking at the wrong part for the job.

Comment: Short propagation delay, if any.

Comment: @Janka - yeah I never do anything fast enough to have to worry about that, but "short" or "long" is application relative so the most precise thing I can say is "clear" (as in stated in a datasheet)