# So, ?nobody? makes a high(er) current tri state driver chip?

Tags: driver, led-driver

I'm wanting to charlieplex some 100ma LEDs, and I can hardly believe no one makes a higher output tri state driver.

I know how to do it with discretes, but Prove me wrong, please.

Comment: Use half bridges.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between driver and transistor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/408535/difference-between-driver-and-transistor)

Comment: @WesleyLee I don’t think so. This question is specific about Charlieplexing.

Answer (score 2):

That's probably because you are looking for the wrong term. At those currents you are likely to have to look for [darlington transistor arrays](https://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/DiodesULN200234ADNPAJune4.PDF), or [NFET transistor arrays](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpl7407l.pdf), not mere "drivers".

To charlieplex, you would need to combine low-side and [high-side](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/408/TBD62785AFWG_datasheet_en_20170530-1313559.pdf) drivers.

It's similar to working with discretes, but a bunch of all the needed parts are inside just two ICs :)

You can also use H-bridge drivers (or motor drivers) for this purpose.

Comment: Im using the tern "driver" generically.

Comment: Im using the tern "driver" generically.
"you would need to combine low-side and high-side drivers."  Yes; they call that a tri-state driver.

I forgot about the SN754410 H driver.   Too bad only half is usable due to the EN lines tied to driver pairs.

Comment: Combining an 8-channel high-side driver with an 8-channel low-side driver is at least 14 components smaller than an individual transistor solution (13 if you use an external inverter), and only 1 component more than a (nonexistent) 3-state driver.

Comment: "...8-channel high-side driver..."
Yeah.   A part #'d be helpful.

Comment: "..and only 1 component more than a (nonexistent) 3-state driver..."
and if its non-existant, how many components do you think it replaces??

Comment: The low side is trivial.....
 the link to https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/408/TBD62785AFWG_datasheet_en_20170530-1313559.pdf is exactly what I was asking.   Thanks.

NOT off-topic, BTW.